# How to make an integrated address based on a subaddress?

Tags: testnet, integrated-address, sub-address

Monero is getting subaddresses soon. How are integrated addresses built upon those?

I'm trying the standard algorithm, using netbyte `0x35` (I'm on testnet) but the wallet rejects them as invalid.

Example:

- subaddress: `BdZHh8j3gieLUtCWEQqQWRbakvLCvffrfMkUALrrAi2gHMrwfRzeeqHM2ZMCPzpqhg5ZsgHJQmAev3i7epY6yV7NJYQNfWf`
- PID: `c28347cea0f01641`
- IA: `4Ghh5chLvwtLUtCWEQqQWRbakvLCvffrfMkUALrrAi2gHMrwfRzeeqHM2ZMCPzpqhg5ZsgHJQmAev3i7epY6yV7NT44nkedwuth8Mp7yns`

However, with my algorithm and also with the address tester at https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html the base address computed back from the IA is:
`47124osrKgNLUtCWEQqQWRbakvLCvffrfMkUALrrAi2gHMrwfRzeeqHM2ZMCPzpqhg5ZsgHJQmAev3i7epY6yV7NJZKb2gx`

Before I dig into the source, can someone tell me if there are some rules I must follow when making IAs, or this is just not possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't. Subaddresses also solve the problem integrated addresses were designed for (allowing source identification in a single address). Since you can now generate a subaddress per source/client/customer, you don't need to assign a payment id anymore, so the ability to make integrated subaddresses was not added.